# Hard code Id problem on home page component in salesforce?

Tags: home-page-component

[image: Hard code Id Problem in Home page componenet]

**I have created a home page component Image type. I have selected  image from document folder, and now it is showing as a hard coded id, How I can avoid this   hard code id .**

Comment: Have you looked into using a static resource instead?

Comment: Here we can not use static resources.

Comment: That would be helpful to add to your question and also why.

Comment: This looks standard home page component layout. When you upload the image, salesforce generates the image tag automatically referring the document you uploaded. Are you asking how to stop SFDC from generating the image tag with id's?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Setup / Develop / Static Resources. You can upload image files here and refer to them by name (e.g. /resource/myImage). You can also migrate these files as part of a change set.

Answer (score 1):

Are you are asking on how to hide the Body tag inside the Home Page Component?
then the answer is you cannot edit the layout of Home Page Component

You can only edit the Home Page Layout using the Number of Home page components

You can only assign links, image, etc and can add them to Home Page....

Answer (score 0):

The image you have posted is of the Home Page Component's detail page which is defined by SFDC. If you want to add this component to the home page layout, you have to go

```
Setup-->Customize-->Home-->Home Page Layout
```

and add the component to the layout(Check the checkbox against the component).

In case, you want to view what the image is, you can directly go the image URL which is specified in src and see it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am asking , How to avoid hard code id?

Comment: Why do you need the ID to be dynamic? How you are going to use the SFDC standard record layout. Could you please explain?

Comment: Hard code is is not a best practise.